# ArgumentNullException unhandled

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm new to C#. I have an implicit typed variable defined like this:

```
 var item = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body[@id='person']")
                                  .Select(p => p.InnerText);
```

This var sometimes returns `null`. And that's where visual studio asks me to handle the `ArgumentNullException`. But if I do that my `var` remains unknown to the rest of my `try`-`catch` and I can no longer use it.

Someone advised me to use the null object design pattern but I don't how am I supposed to implement it for a `var`. Does anyone know how I should handle such situations because I'm tired of handling the null case each and every time.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? We need some more information in order to help you. What code have you tried? What Try-catch block are you talking about?

Comment: A `Select()` call in LINQ to Objects will never just return `null`, it will always return something.  Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @Rik nothing really. I don't want my code to stop executing because of that ArgumentNullException, but at the same time if I catch that error then my var item will be unknown to the rest of my code.

Comment: What *exactly* has the value `null`?

Comment: @Deestan my item can give me null. But that's okay with me. I need to know if it gives me null so I can check something.

Comment: @sixlettervariables, `Select` will throw an `ArgumentNullException` if the `this` argument is `null`.

Comment: @ThomSmith: I wrote that before I realized this was HAP related. You won't get a `null` from `XmlNode.SelectNodes`. I've revised the tags and removed my comments suggesting otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming, as it seems, that the problem is `SelectNodes` returning `null` when no results are found. This is a pattern I come across frequently: a sequence of operations, several of which can return `null` values, where the production of any `null` should cause the entire sequence to produce `null`.

One solution is to use what functional programmers would call the `Maybe` monad's `Bind` method:

```
public static U IfNotNull<T, U>(this T self, Func<T, U> func)
    where U : class
{
    return (self != null) ? func(self) : null;
}
```

This will "propagate" nulls rather than throwing exceptions. Then,

```
doc.DocumentNode
    .SelectNodes("//body[@id='person']")
    .IfNotNull(nodes => nodes.Select(p => p.InnerText));
```

If `SelectNodes` returned `IEnumerable<XmlNode>`, you could use `Enumerable.Empty<>`:

```
(doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body[@id='person']") ?? Enumerable.Empty<XmlNode>())
    .Select(p => p.InnerText);
```

Or, for better readability, write an extension method to avoid worrying about operator syntax:

```
public static T Coalesce<T>(this T self, T other)
    where T : class
{
    return self ?? other;
}
```

And:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body[@id='person']")
    .Coalesce(Enumerable.Empty<XmlNode>())
    .Select(p => p.InnerText);
```

These are all various ways of deferring null checks until you're ready to deal with the results, without having to catch `NullPointerException`s (or `ArgumentException`s in the case of extension methods). Note that any of these that produce `null` values could produce default values instead if you tossed a simple `??` operator at the end.

Comment: The OP is not receiving a NullPointerException. Although, it appears that HTML Agility Pack breaks tradition and returns `null` with `SelectNodes`, so perhaps they are receiving that exception and didn't ask their question correctly.

Comment: You're right, of course. I expect what's happening is that the `Select` extension method is throwing the `ArgumentNullException`, which, in the case of extension methods, is sort of cognate to a `NullPointerException` on an ordinary method call in terms of the overall effect and how one deals with them. The techniques I presented will work equally well for ordinary and extension method calls, and will help to manage null receivers in the former case and null arguments in the latter case.

Comment: Apparently HAP breaks LINQ, it's too bad folks have to use code like yours. But +1 for a way out of the woods.

Comment: @Thom Smith: I added your Coalesce function and your bottommost line (doc.DocumentNode...) instead of my previous var declaration and I'm getting this error: 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Coalesce' and no extension method 'Coalesce' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Wherever you put the `Coalesce`, it can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnymerable<HtmlNode> v = null;    
var item = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body[@id='person']");
if (item != null)
{
    v = item.Select(p => p.InnerText);
}
```

Comment: your var v = null line gives an error of "Cannot assign <null> to an implicitly-typed local variable".

Comment: Pff. Use something else insted of `var` then. What the problem? `IEnumerable<HtmlNode>`...